# Selecting records when a criteria is met

Tags: sql, ssms

I am trying to come up with a SQL that will NOT select records when error value is "true" and when the name of that person as well as the date are the same.  I thought perhaps a main query using the IN function where the parameter would be a sub query that will identify what the duplicates are for User_ID and Error_Dt.  So for example:

Sample Data:

```
+----------+-------+---------+----------+
| Error_ID | Error | User_ID | Error_Dt | 
+----------+-------+---------+----------+
| Err_A_01 | True  | JP_123  | 20200307 |
| Err_A_02 | True  | DF_455  | 20200605 |
| Err_A_03 | True  | DF_455  | 20200605 |
| Err_A_04 | False | DF_455  | 20200703 |
| Err_B_01 | False | BH_135  | 20200219 |
| Err_B_02 | True  | DP_246  | 20200310 |
| Err_B_03 | True  | DP_246  | 20200310 |
| Err_B_04 | True  | DP_246  | 20200509 |
| Err_B_05 | False | DP_246  | 20200601 |
| Err_B_06 | True  | KS_159  | 20200120 |
| Err_B_07 | True  | KS_159  | 20200120 |
| Err_B_08 | True  | KS_159  | 20200310 |
| Err_C_01 | False | JH_123  | 20200702 |
+----------+-------+---------+----------+
```

Desire Results:

```
+----------+-------+---------+----------+
| Error_ID | Error | User_ID | Error_Dt | 
+----------+-------+---------+----------+
| Err_A_01 | True  | JP_123  | 20200307 |
| Err_A_04 | False | DF_455  | 20200703 |
| Err_B_01 | False | BH_135  | 20200219 |
| Err_B_04 | True  | DP_246  | 20200509 |
| Err_B_05 | False | DP_246  | 20200601 |
| Err_B_08 | True  | KS_159  | 20200310 |
| Err_C_01 | False | JH_123  | 20200702 |
+----------+-------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Will you ever have two records for the same `User_ID`/`Error_Dt` that are both have `Error` = false?

Comment: @D M - For this example, no.

Answer (score 1):

Select only unique `Error + User_ID + Error_Dt` rows or those not  'True'.

```
select Error_ID, Error, User_ID, Error_Dt
from (
    select *,
      count(*) over(partition by Error, User_ID, Error_Dt) cnt
    from tbl ) t
where Error <> 'True' OR cnt = 1
order by Error_ID;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works out perfectly!  Now to apply this to my duplication issue which is a struggle.